# PHP easy-to-solve

Tags: php

```
<?
[...]
$line = fgets($file);
while(!feof($file)){
        if(($line)!==('da7or')){
        {
    echo fgets($file)."<br />";
        }
}}
[...]
?>
```

file is something like:
nick1
da7or
nick3
nick4
nick5

I don't want "da7or" to be displayed but it always removes nick from the 1st line of the file.

Comment: Perhaps it is because you are using "!==" instead of "!="

Comment: you are calling fgets twice at the start.. outside the while loop and once inside.. for the test you are using the "old" value and for output the second one

Answer (score 2):

since you are calling twice fgets try somthing like:

```
[..]
while(!feof($file))
{
    $line = trim(fgets($file));
    if(($line)!==('da7or'))
    {
        echo $line ."<br />";
    }
}
[..]
```

notice there's no fgets before the while

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` also returns linebreak characters. You'll have to do

```
if (trim($line) !== 'da7or')
```

to strip off those characters. Note that if any of your lines also START with whitespace characters, trim will also remove those as well.
Beyond that, your logic is flawed.

You fetch a line, compare is against da7or, then simply directly output every line AFTER this. Your loop should be:

```
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
    if (trim($line) !== 'da7or') {
       echo $line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop to read in a file line-wise is kinda stupid.
Because there is a function for that: [`file()`](http://php.net/file)

```
$names = file("names.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$names = array_diff($names, array("da7or"));
```

And the simple [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) removes the unwanted element from the list. Then just print out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You never update `$line` after the first time.

```
<?php
while (!feof($file) && $line = fgets($file))
{
    if (trim($line) != 'da7or')
        echo $line;
}
```

Comment: he does update it by calling it when he makes the output.. but the problem is that he calls it again before the while.. and for the test he users the previous value always

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose, if you read the file line into $line you can't echo the fgets, you need to echo $line (and reload the $line variables with a fget)